# SQL Server: "a connection was successfully established with server....existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Tags: sql-server

Yes folks, it's this one again.

> "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then
>   an error occurred during the login process  (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host.)"

I'm sorry...  I *have* Google'd this, I *have* read the other StackOverflow articles on this problem, and I *have* tried all kinds of suggestions, but nothing works.

Here's a few notes about what we're seeing.

1. This issue occurs occassionally in *SQL Server Management Studio* itself (doing any kind of database activity... getting a list of tables in a database, having a look at a Stored Procedure, etc)
2. It also happens in *Visual Studio 2010* itself, when it is trying to get data from the servers (e.g. when creating a .dbml file, etc)
3. It also sometimes happens in our .Net (ASP, WPF, Silverlight) applications.
4. Our SQL Server 2005 & 2008 servers are all based on virtual machines in data centres around the world, and we see sometimes this error on each of them.  But most of the time, they all work absolutely fine.
5. When the error does occur, we can just "retry" what caused the error, and then it'll work fine.
6. We think..  if we have an IIS Web Server in a data centre in a particular city, and it accesses a SQL Server in the same data centre, then we *don't* see the issue.
7. We think..  if we connect to the servers, and specify the UserID and Password to use, it causes this error much more frequently than if we just use Active Directory authentication.

Put all that together, and it sounds to me like some kind of network issue.
But can anyone suggest what to look for ?

This isn't a bug in our .Net applications, as even *SQL Server Management Studio* "trips up" with this error.

It's baffling us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512153/provider-ssl-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by)

Answer (score 9):

Just in case anyone else hits this issue, we finally found the solution.

Our company uses *Riverbed* software to compress data, when it's being passed between locations, and this was somehow causing some connections to get dropped.

Our IT gurus found a configuration setting which finally fixed this issue.

I believe there's a setting in there to turn off compressing results from SQL Server (or something like that).  That fixed it for us.

Comment: Can you please add MSSQL configuration setting to resolve the issue?

Comment: @EvgenyBychkov Did you find that setting?

Comment: @ThanosDarkadakis the setting is in their RIverbed software, not in SQL Server. If you don't have Riverbed software, this answer does not apply to you.

Answer (score 6):

Try turning off your VPN if you have one enabled; this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30312519)

Comment: This was the answer for me; my corp uses a VPN for resource/ DB access, and something ended up being wrong on the VPN's side, which was causing this issue for me (and many other folks in the org). "Turning off the VPN" wasn't really the solution, since I can't access our internal resources without it, but this was at least what put me down the right track!

Answer (score 5):

It could be any number of network issues.  ANYTHING that prevents the code from reaching the server even for the few miliseconds it takes to make one query.

it could also be the result of a failover.  When we went from a single SQL Server to a clustered environment, we'd see this happen during a failover.  In this case, it turned out to be our Connection Pooling.  In essence, the SQL cluster has a controller and two servers behind it.  A and B.

Say our web app is using server A just fine,  Connection pooling creates a connection on both sides.  The server is aware of it, and the web app is aware of it.  Once the cluster fails over to the second server, the web app is aware of the connection but server B is not, so we get an error.

The point is, any possible cause of network issues imaginable may be the cause.  DOS attacks on the server, man-in-the middle attacks intercepting and changing traffic.  Someone trips on an ethernet cable and it's loose in the jack.  You name it, if it can cause a connection issue, it could be the cause.

Your issue also sounds like one we had recently - we also have a virtual environment, wih software that moves VMs from one host to another as needed for load balancing.  Every so often, we'd get bombarded with the same error. It turned out to be an issue with the NIC drivers on one of the hosts, so whenever a VM moved to that particular host, errors would occur.

It's really not a programming issue.  It's an environment issue, and you need trained professionals with direct access to your environment to research and resolve this.

Comment: Perhaps you can suggest some debugging techniques or software to track down the source of the issue in other environments?

Comment: Debugging techniques: e.g. use Wireshark to diagnose the SSL/TLS handshake to verify it's completing successfully.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I was inadvertently using a wireless network to connect to our network because the Ethernet cable was faulty.  This after repairing SQL Server, running a Winsock reset as recommended elsewhere ...

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing the same issue and our app interfaces with a several Azure SQL DBs. I believe (same as you) I do not have a bug in the C# code to cause this issue. We've solved it by a simple **for loop** containing an extra attempts to try to connect to the Azure SQL again if the previous attempt fails and then run the query.

Most of the time everything runs fine but sometimes we can see the loop kicked-in and on the 2nd or 3rd time it executed properly without the below mentioned error. After that we see in the log file the error below for all the unsuccessful attempts:

```
    A connection was successfully established with the server,
but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP
Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
remote host.)
```

Even though this is a **less-then-pretty solution**, it allowed us to run our app without interruptions. I know you've mentioned that trying to connect again (to introduce some connection-failure tolerance) solves the problem and unfortunately this is the only correct solution I found so far as well.

I should mention that we have tried many debugging strategies to figure this out. **Right now it all points to the availability of the database we are trying to connect to i.e.: It happens if the number of allowed DB connections is exceeded. (or so it seems at this time)**

Comment: this error also happened to me with SQL Azure, but I the real issue is that I had a connection open too long while debugging - letting the app run naturally worked fine. May just have to increase the connection timeout - `SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout`, NOT the `CommandTimeout`.

Comment: I remember that we once ran out of connections on a Azure database and the error message told us explicitly that it was the case. I have the same problem, but I have  a queue with retry. I think the problem might be related to network issues or SynAck attack prevention.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was seeing this error intermittently from a .Net application connecting to a SQL server located in the same server room. It turned out that some of the databases had auto close turned on which caused the server to close the connections in the pool. When the application tried to use one of the pool connections that had been closed, it would throw this error and I saw a log message on the SQL server that the database it was trying to connect to was being started. Auto-close has now been turned off on those databases and the error hasn't been seen since.

Also, having auto-close on is the default behavior for SQL Express databases and these were originally created on an Express instance during testing before being migrated to the production server where we were seeing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening in our code when we were opening the dbconnection for oracle and were passing DBtype as SQL in our database object.

Answer (score 0):

in my case - the error was Microsoft first suggestion:
Client is connecting with an unsupported version of the SQL Server Native Client.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, We got this error when we updated sql server to sp3. We were not able to connect to the database from SSIS package.

We updated the native client and configurations. We were able to connect.

link to download the native client  - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50402

Link for configurations settings and further troubleshooting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187005(v=sql.105)

Hope it helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same type of issue.  In my case it was a bit more complicated... I could connect to “ServerA” from “ServerB” via SSMS, but it would fail with sqlcmd.  The error was the same:

*Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

I could also connect from “ServerC” with both SSMS and sqlcmd.  The following are the versions on the VMs:

```
ServerA: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter / Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU10) (KB4025925) - 11.0.6607.3 (X64) 
ServerB: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter / Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)
ServerC: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter / Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-CU10) (KB4025925) - 11.0.6607.3 (X64)
```

Bottom line was the “unsupported version”.  I noticed a mismatch of “sqlncli11.dll” between ServerC and ServerB, so I copied it to the System32 folder.  After this, sqlcmd worked like a charm.  Below were the versions in my case:

```
Failed:
FileVersion:      2011.0110.5058.00
ProductVersion:   11.0.5058.0

Worked:
FileVersion:      2011.0110.6607.03
ProductVersion:   11.0.6607.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on 2 projects at the same time (on 2 different machines) and both used SQL Server.

When i disconnected SQL with 1 machine the errorMessage went away. Probably you can mess around with IP-adresses too to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this answer is for those how have this problem with Azure Sql server database.

It happens when you reach mat pool

first remove `Persist Security Info=False` from connection string
second check your database plan in azure portal and increase the PTUs of your database plan.

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS "Connect to Server" screen click Options, then on "Connection Properties" TAB change "Network protocol" to "Named Pipes"

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

- Click Start, point to All Programs, and click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- Click to expand SQL Server Network Configuration and then click Client Protocols.
- Right-click the TCP/IP protocol and then click Enable.
- Right-click the Named Pipes protocol and then click Enable.
- Restart the SQL server service if prompted to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue a couple of time already, and I've fixed by reducing the MTU size. Often 1350, 1250, etc on my network interface.