# Dealing with earlier version of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

So I'm asked to make an web app to display the content of an database. 
The problem is, I don't seem to be able to connect to the database from `Visual Studio 2015`, because the database is created with **`SQL Server 7.0`** and upgrading it is out of question, so I have to find a way to retrieve data from it without altering it in any way and nothing.

I found on the internet seems to help so far, any advice on what I should do?
so far, here's my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WebApp1
{
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnct = new SqlConnection("Server=x.x.x.x;User ID=xx;Password=xx;Database=xxxx"))
            {
                try
                {

                    cnct.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select code from societe", cnct))
                    {

                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            string code = rdr.GetString(1);
                        }

                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering that SQL Server 2000, the successor to SQL Server 7 fell out of even extended support in 2013, it's beyond time for them to consider an upgrade.

Comment: I believe, simply SqlConnection() works. What have you tried so far?

Comment: well, they still use the SQL Server 7 database til this day, and I have to squeeze out the internet of a way to give them what they ask for

Comment: SqlConnection didn't work for me

Comment: I don't see any connection code.

Comment: there I added the code

Comment: what error do you get on connection.open?

Comment: "I don't seem to be able to connect" isn't enough information.  Please give the result of all of your debugging.  What errors did you get, or what other issues / symptoms did you encounter?  You need to give full and detailed information.

Comment: I don't, the error shows when I build the solution and open it on browser

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever they should consider it, but in some cases there is a perfectly legitimate business case for continuing to use an 18 year old, no longer supported product.

Comment: @MohamedaliHamdi - I would capture extra error information, then log or at least display it, so we all know what the error is.  Can you otherwise use the database? can you make any connection to it from a .udl file for example (make new text file on desktop, change name from .txt to .udl, then try and connect to db) - ' perfectly legitimate business case' yes indeed!  Like avoiding doing a hell of a lot of work/upgrading/spending money/ taking huge time over legacy system etc...

Comment: For one thing, and I don't know because I forgot if I ever used this DB - were connection strings the same then?  You have to get the full error logged, to a text file or something, or just dump it to the screen - or find docs on connection strings - or check that a connection can be made via some other method.

Comment: [this is the error that show when I build my project](http://imgur.com/a/sNeQq)

Comment: Please make the basic effort of copy/pasting the error into your question. Anyway, according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719765(v=vs.71).aspx, .net 1.1 should connect OK but I'm guessing you're using a much later version. Can you connect using the Enterprise Manager tool? You might want to try going through ODBC to connect. You might also need to specifically install some older driver and use that. Can you connect through ODBC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890971/sql-server-a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-server-existing-c

Comment: Make sure the database name is correct and make sure that your User (ID=xx) has connection rights to the database.

Comment: Also check your SQL Client manager for the Encryption/SSL setting (I'm not sure where this is for SS2000, might be in ODBC Connections).  Try toggling it to something else.  also, this answer might be helpful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80756/disabled-ssl-on-sql-server-now-connection-fails

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm trying to use ODBC but it doesn't recognize OdbcDataReader.executeReader

Comment: Close Visual Studio. Do some connectivity tests using Enterprise Manager and ODBC Administrator.